# What is the difference between the int used by View.VISIBLE and normal ints?

Tags: java, android

If I want to toggle the visibility of a TextView, I can use ***View.VISIBLE*** or ***View.INVISIBLE***

According to the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility), VISIBLE is 0 and INVISIBLE is 1.

But it doesn't work if I use setvisibility(0)

Why does View.VISIBLE work but not 0?

Comment: It works for me... if I use setVisibility(0) the item gets visible.

Comment: If View.Visible is 0 in your Android Library this should be impossible.

Comment: setVisibility(1) also makes it visible but it should be invisible

Comment: @mrburns - As per my answer, `INVISIBLE` is actually 4.  The documentation is incorrect when it says the value is 1.  Try using `setVisibility(4)`.  Also try logging out the value of `View.VISIBLE` to confirm that it really is 0 in the SDK version you are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [source code](http://hi-android.info/src/android/view/View.java.html) is always a valid option with Android.  One thing that is immediately apparent is that `INVISIBLE` is *not* 1:

```
/**
 * This view is visible.  Use with {@link #setVisibility}.
 */
public static final int VISIBLE = 0x00000000;

/**
 * This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
 * Use with {@link #setVisibility}.
 */
public static final int INVISIBLE = 0x00000004;
```

However, `VISIBLE` is indeed 0, so using a literal 0 should work.  All `setVisibility()` really does is delegate to `setFlags()` with the number you pass it and `VISIBILITY_MASK`, which is 0x0C (12).

Comment: Thanks. I think it looks like I read the documentation wrong. I think those 0, 1, 2 values are for the xml file, and the VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, GONE ints are when using it in code.

Answer (score 1):

These int values can change all the time and that's why you need to be careful when using the numeric as opposed to enum-like parameter (I know it not an enum... just saying).

if you really want to know the value behind those parameters use:

```
hello.setText(Integer.toString(View.INVISIBLE))
```

with hello being a TextView.

in this case, the answer is 4 (`.GONE` is 8)

Answer (score 0):

Best way:

```
private void setViewVisiblity(int visiblity){
        Button b = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        b.setVisibility(visiblity);
}

// for visible: 
setViewVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)

// for invisible: 
setViewVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE)

// for gone: 
setViewVisiblity(View.GONE)
```